# occasionally when the populated PDF is opened the text only appears when the body field is clicked

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I am using Apache PDFbox to populate a two page template which includes a couple of Body fields (Body1 and Body2) I populate them with paragraphs of text, most of the time this works great, however..

occasionally when the populated PDF is opened the text only appears when the body field is clicked. click out of that field and text disappears

I have seen this behavior occasionally in both the Body1 and Body2 field.

Comment: That's too bad. Good luck figuring that out. Did you have a programming question?

Comment: Yes, I am wondering anyone was seen a similar behavior is their program that populates PDF templates that causes the text to not appear until that fields is clicked.

Comment: This is because the "appearance stream" isn't calculated when assigning the value. This is a known problem in some 1.8 versions. Are you using the latest version (1.8.10)? There it has been solved for some field types, but not all. It has been solved for all in the unreleased 2.0 version.

Comment: I was using 1.8.2, I updated the application to now use 1.8.10 and will monitor the results.  thanks for the assistance..